# Microsoft Web Platform Installer 4.0 fail

Tags: iis, download, installation, webmatrix

Because my hard drive is nearly full, I find I don't use the (full)IIS7 and uninstall it to release hard drive space in my vista computer.

However, after that, I can't do many download installations through 'Microsoft Web Platform Installer 4.0", for example, download and install webMatrix 2.

I install the  IIS8 express, I still can't do many download installation through MWPI 4.0, even I can't uninstall the MWPI from my computer. thanks advanced

Comment: I upgraded my machine to Windows 8 Pro. My machine is a 64-bit dual core. I too cannot uninstall mwpi, no matter what I try. When uninstalling from control panel is just gets so far and you see the progress bar rollback to its previous state. Reinstalling mwpi tries to uninstall and an error is reported because of rollback.

This Microsoft Web Platform Installer 4.0 appears to be unpleasantly resilient.

Answer (score 1):

I talked to the guys on the WebPI team, and they confirmed there is a bug.  WebPI installs a plugin into inetmgr that occasionally doesn't get cleaned up after uninstalling IIS.  THis causes WebPI a lot of trouble.  Give this a try:

- Install Full IIS
- Uninstall existing WebPI
- Uninstall Full IIS
- Re-install WebPI

After doing these steps, everything should work.  Sorry for the confusion.